# XML Parsing error getting extra node comes <br/> in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web-services, nsxmlparser

I am new to iPhone application development, i have used the web services and get the response in the xml format. I have used the NSXML parser for parsing those data and i have some problem when i parsed the xml data. Because one extra node `<br/>`, so i couldn't parsed the content. So parsing will be blocked on that particular data after that exception throws(EXC_BAD_ACCES).

Here my sample data format,

```
<Company>
<Offer>
<OfferDescription>2 for $20 menu<br/>1/2 price late night appetizers</OfferDescription>
<OfferType>1</OfferType>
</Offer>
</Company>
```

So please help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: If you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal you are doing something wrong with memory management (usually you are trying to send a message to a deallocated object when you get this). It hasn't got anything to do with XML.

Comment: The XML is valid, since XML does allow the `<br />` within the tag. Thus you will be unable to parse it.

Comment: then how can we come up with this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to replace your 
 tag with "". Might be you can use following -

```
NSString *myDataString = [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br/>" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is you used "`</Company>`" as your beginning tag in your sample set.  Try "`<Company>`" on the first line instead and see what happens.

Hope this helps.